# ACRA email not sending

Tags: android, email, logging, acra

I try to implement ACRA in my app so that I can get crash reports by email. I have this code in my application class:

```
@ReportsCrashes(mailTo = "me@mydomain.com")
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

I already gave the internet permission to my app since I use it. In my logcat, it says that ACRA is initialized and that i caught an exception, but I don't have any email in my inbox.

Someone has any clue? Thanks!

Comment: What version of ACRA? ACRA should be starting your email client with the crash report attached.

Comment: ACRA 4.8.5 and yeah I know, that's why I'm bugged :X

Comment: Have you solved this? I've got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Is ACRA asking for an email app when this exception occurs? Maybe You have strange email app set that doesn't send email at all.

Comment: No, it doesn't ask for anything.. I'll try with mail.jar or something

Comment: And no default are set

Comment: Did You change <application android:name=.../> to MyApp in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Right now it is `android:name=".MyApp"` does it make a difference that there is a dot? I've tried with and without it without success..

Comment: It depends on the path. If your package is set as package="your.main.package" and MyApp is in path your.main.package.application.MyApp android:name should be set to ".application.MyApp". Try to print some Logs in MyApp onCreate